# Members Group - Unable to View Users

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365-groups

I am unable to view the members of the default groups and it only lists the AD account created when the site was originally created.

I am not a 365 Admin, just the site owner. I was previously able to view the users and remove a user through the advanced permissions screen. I now only have access through the memberlist on the home page.

Is this something Microsoft just did and it's by design? Or did my IT department possibly do something?

I was thinking I might have accidentally deleted something. However, I have another team site where the issue is replicated (separate site entirely, not a sub-site).

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure that the privacy of the O365 group is set to Public ?

Comment: Do you mean you suddenly lose access to "Site permissions"? Can you access advanced permission settings of the site via "https://.../_layouts/15/user.aspx"?

Answer (score 1):

This is a permissions issue. Ask the 365 Admin to elevate your permissions.

Instructions:

Site Settings > People and Groups > *select group you are a member of* > Settings > Group settings

Here, you can toggle two settings:

- Who can view the membership of the group? "Group Members" or "Everyone"
- Who can edit the membership of the group? "Group Owner" or "Group Members"

This will apply to the group itself, so please ensure that the other members of this group are intended to have the same level of permissions. If this is not the case, you may want to request to be moved from one group to another.

I hope this clarifies!

### EDIT

- A question on your permissions EStein, you say you are a `Site Owner`.  I think this term is muddying the issue - a site owner would normally have the `Full Control` permissions (meaning they can do more or less anything when administrating a site).  I think you've been told you are the site owner in the sense of 'this site has been set up for you and you are kind of responsible for it' rather than being the Site Owner in a technical/permissions sense.
- There are plenty of MS instructions on permissions - [for example here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/understand-groups-and-permissions-on-a-sharepoint-site-258e5f33-1b5a-4766-a503-d86655cf950d#:~:targetText=A%20site%20owner%20usually%20grants,a%20member%20of%20the%20group.).

Following up Sarah's explanation, please see the screen shot below (after all, a picture paints a thousand words):

[image]

Comment: What specific setting? I asked and was informed they did not change anything. They will not elevate my permissions, unfortunately.

Comment: Editing comment for more details.

Comment: Sarah, your reply is about SP group, while his question is about O365 group

Comment: I agree with Sarah, I also think it is a permissions issue.  Even if it transpires that it is not, it is worth investigating

Comment: Thanks, Tally, for the further clarification for EStein!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I actually am a site owner and have full control. It's the same thing in SPD - I can see the "Members" group but cannot actually view anyone in that group, despite being a site owner with full control. I don't believe this is an O365 group issue.